# LEDs on TX/RX lines interfering with the programmig of the device

Tags: led, shields

I have recently designed a shield to my Arduino Duemilanove, which has 8 LEDs, on the digital GPIO, from 0 to 7, but it won't program with the shield on because the voltage drop is too much on the RX and TX lines. My question is: can I have a LED on the TX/RX line with a minimum resistor value that allows me to program the Arduino?

Comment: how do you have the pins configured/wired? Pullups/pulldowns? Are you sinking current or providing current to the LEDs?

Comment: I have from `digital pin 0(RX)-->330R-->LED-->GND`, and its pretty annoying on the developing fase to be constantly taking on and off the shield.

Comment: try something in the order of 5-15k and see how that goes. If brightness becomes an issue you might have to put a transistor in as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found this reference ([using ICSP for output as well as programming](http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=printview&t=70515&start=0) -- essentially the same thing), and it suggests a 4.7kOhm.

I didn't have a 4.7k handy, and used a 15k instead and it works.

In my scenario, I have run a sketch with a polarized buzzer connected between RX (digital 0) and `GND`. When connected directly (with no resistor) the sketch fails to load (but the buzzer works as expected).

If I put the resistor in series with it, the sketch uploads without fail.

You also probably realise, but mentioning for clarity/completeness, you will lose all serial port functionality for debugging purposes and won't be able to use `Serial.[anything]`. Make sure to not even initialise the port.

Comment: After trying several resistor sizes i got to the smallest possible size of **470R**, now i can program whitout any problems at least for this kind of LED, it will probably change if you have an LED with a bigger voltage drop, thank you very much again for your help @Madivad :).

Comment: Oh well, that saves me from finishing this project. I was just putting together a breadboard to try different values myself. Glad I could help.

Comment: Thats some dedicated fellow :), if your interested i can show you my shield it will be shared soon on OSH Park.
Is there a way to contact people here with private messages ?

Comment: Well, I was using it as a learning experience for me as well. Which is why I answer a few XBee questions. As far as I know there is no PM system, but just below in the footer is a "chat", head over to "pin13"